# Azure SQL Database - Restore options for Continuous Integration Builds

Tags: backup, restore, azure-sql-database

We have a Azure SQL Database (PAAS) that acts like a master database for testing new code.

The goal is to set up a pipeline that creates a writeable copy of the master database to test new builds continuously during the day. All the data in the database is needed to be able to perform tests.

Backup/Restore/Copy(?) is a too slow operation for this scenario since the database is too big.
Contaniners is not an option.

Is there any other smart way to create a writeable copy/snapshot of a Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Define "too big"

Comment: I don't have the numbers, only that a copy database operation takes too much time. This also created problems in the pipeline. They are looking for alternate methods of doing it.

Comment: So, @Stephen Morris reply is correct

Answer (score 2):

fastest way I know to get a database copy in Azure is to use the TSQL syntax

```
CREATE DATABASE ... AS COPY OF ...
```

see the official docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=sqlpool#copy-a-database

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe I should look into an alternative like moving the master database to a VM and use File Snapshot-backups/restore if Copy is the fastest process for the PAAS database.